# Visual Studio Code - PowerShell debugging (global variables and Intellisense)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, global-variables, intellisense, powershell-ise

I need some help here. I think Visual Studio Code is a great replacement for PowerShell ISE, however, there a few things that I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if VS Code is just buggy yet. When debugging my PowerShell code, not only Intellisense does not work (I press the up/down button and nothing happens - Using the latest VS Code available and the latest PS Extension) and for a a very strange reason when I set a global variable in my code VS Code creates it as a Local variable instead.

Here is what I get in VS_Code:

[image: Screenshot of global Variables in VS_Code]

And here is what I get in PS_ISE:

[image: Screenshot of global Variables in PS_ISE]

Because of that, obviously my code crashes because as soon as I change the scope the variables are no longer available.

This is really preventing me from fully using VS Code completely (it forces me to debug code using PS ISE). If I'm doing anything wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce either of your issues, tested on 1.33.1 and 1.40.0. If you haven't already, I might try reinstalling the tool from scratch. Or if possible, test on a different machine.